# VS CODE Showing some weird pattern

Tags: visual-studio-code

I believe that this problem is due to some graphics card settings but I am unable to put my finger on it.

[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling vscode and download a complete new installer from their website. You can also try starting it from the command line with this command: `code --disable-gpu`. (btw do you have a amd gpu?)

Comment: *"graphics card settings"* Yes. Set all of them to "respect the application settings" (or whatever it's called), and disable any kind of image sharpness adjustments.